# My previous question was totally serious, but was closed down

Tags: discussion

Alan Wallace site suggested I post any question here. Clearly this was a mistake. Please close my account here.

Comment: might wanna try dhammawheel.com also. You might have better luck there..

Comment: Sorry you didn't get the answer you were hoping for. You can ask most questions here -- but maybe not [that one](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/38809/254), for reasons which aren't easy to explain. You can simply abandon your account here if you don't want to reuse it in future; or if you want to delete your account, please see [How do I delete my account?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account)

Comment: You can delete your account from [here](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/delete/19054).

Comment: Dharmawheel.com is the mahayana version of that forum Santa mentioned. This site is imo better tho.

Answer (score 3):

Your question should've been posed differently imo. Offering money to people and furthermore inquiring about highly attained lay people is just not going to turn out very well for a number of reasons.

The first answer you got was a person taking a stab at another member by bringing up his controversial bio. There is no way that the poster gave that answer in good faith as the two have been going back and forth before and he obviously doesn't think much of Andrei and probably the whole tradition..

I would've commented but i actually taught people involved or mod would take action.

This is a good place for Q/A but as the russian saying goes 'semja ne bez uroda'.

I think a better way to pose the question is
- Looking for serious practitioners of XYZ
- How can one best realize the idea of supporting lay people in retreat

I think your question was reasonable and i hope you find someone worthwhile dealing with.

I also think you shouldn't feel unwelcome because it is hard to moderate this platform and there are people who would vote down anything that is out of the ordinary.

At last i'll say that the public here is very mainstream. It's my impression that <5% are studying. People are mostly interested in reading about how 'Buddhism ruined someone's relationship', 'a science vs Buddhism thread' or 'how to deal with a difficult situation' so these are the types of topics that are most agreeable to people in general. Theory and study topics get just a fraction of a fraction the engagement.

Some members also hold conflicting views and love to start a fight. Mods probably closed your question just because foreseeing that you wouldn't get a good answer and that it could turn problematic. I don't think you broke any rules but the question is probably a bit too controversial so people are also looking out for your interest.

The context being 'whom do i give my money to' and favoring one tradition over others, so maybe people get jealous and start posting out of spite when they are not part of that group or get otherwise triggered..